# Summing time by looking at an associated column- an easier way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Project` model that `has_many: Tasks` each Task `has_many :users, through: :userAssociations` so one person can work on a task but in the case of a meeting or any collaboration many users can work on the same task.

Tasks have a column: `t.integer "time"` which allows users to state in minutes the time the task took.

In the Show method of the Project, I'd like to be able to sum the total time that the project has taken.
If not for the fact that a Task can have many users through the userAssociations model, I think this would be very easy: `@project.tasks.sum(:time)` but that won't double count the time if multiple users were working on the task.

Since originally posting this question I was able to get it working with this helper:

```
  def project_time_spent
    @timeSum = 0;

    @tasks.each do |tsk|
      @userTask = UserTask.where(task_id: tsk.id);
      if @userTask.count(:id) > 1
        @timeSum += tsk.time * @userTask.count(:id)
      else
        @timeSum += tsk.time
      end

  end
    return @timeSum
  end
```

But this doesn't feel very "Railsy".  Do any Rails gurus recommend a cleaner approach? Am I missing out on an easy method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a little easier than that since a task has many users. I think you can also use `inject` here.

```
  def project_time_spent
    @tasks.inject { |sum, tsk| sum + (tsk.time * tsk.users.count) }
  end
```

You can include an instance method in your `Project` model:

```
def time_spent
  self.tasks.inject { |sum, tsk| sum + (tsk.time * tsk.users.count) }
end
```

I wouldn't bother checking for count > 1. The savings getting rid of the multiply are minuscule.